# How to set current working directory in python in a automatic way

Tags: python, directory

How can I set the current path of my python file "myproject.py" to the file itself?
I do not want something like this:

```
path = "the path of myproject.py"
```

In mathematica I can set:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

The advantage with the code in Mathematica is that if I change the path of my Mathematica file, for example if I give it to someone else or I put it in another folder, I do not need to do anything extra. Each time Mathematica automatically set the directory to the current folder.

I want something similar to this in Python.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why? Does `myproject.py` need to be imported or just ran from the command line?

Comment: `os.chdir('/path')` or `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: In the myproject.py I have to import some txt files and plot them. os.getcwd() gives the directory which python uses. I want to set the directory in which the python file is, as working directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right solution is not to change the current working directory, but to get the full path to the directory containing your script or module then use `os.path.join` to build your files path:

```
import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# then:
myfile_path = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "myfile.txt")
```

This is safer than messing with current working directory (hint : what would happen if another module changes the current working directory after you did but before you access your files ?)

Comment: @yashar: note: `__file__` fails if the Python file is executed using `execfile('/path/to/myproject.py')`. [`inspect`-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21935564/4279) continues to work.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: thanks for pointing this - I very seldom use `execfile` so never encountered that problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to set the directory in which the python file is, as working directory

There are two step:

1. Find out path to the python file
2. Set its parent directory as the working directory

The 2nd is simple:

```
import os
os.chdir(module_dir) # set working directory
```

The 1st might be complex if you want to support a general case (python file that is run as a script directly, python file that is imported in another module, python file that is symlinked, etc). Here's one [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path#comment15918105_6098238):

```
import inspect
import os

module_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
module_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(module_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) function from the built in `os` module also there's [`os.getcwdu()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwdu) which returns a unicode object of the current working directory

Example usage:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
print path
#C:\Users\KDawG\Desktop\Python
```

Comment: Question asks how to *set* not get.

Comment: @JanneKarila I'm quite confused by what your saying but this is clearly what the OP needs, read the docs

Comment: In the myproject.py I have to import some txt files and plot them. os.getcwd() gives the directory which python uses. I want to set the directory in which the python file is, as working directory. –  yashar